# Reporting services existing in SQL Cluster instance but unable to see on SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, clustering, failover

This is first time I am working on SQL Failover Cluster environment and I installed Reporting services on SQL server Failover Cluster Instance both Active Nodes(Node1 & Node2) and configured through Reporting services configuration manager, when I was opened SSMS I haven't find any Reportserver and ReportserverTempDB Databases. Which means did I miss something in installation? or we have to configure those separately? When I was trying to add Reporting services feature I got an error like below.

[image]

Comment: Did you refresh the list of databases in object explorer in SSMS?

Comment: @JonathanFite   Yes I did.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you never installed anything, with that rule failing you would not have been able to continue the installation (can't click on Next).

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2778/how-to-add-reporting-services-to-an-existing-sql-server-clustered-instance/

Answer (score -1):

If you used the Reporting services configuration manager to configure reporting services, which SQL instance did you point Reporting Services at?  Go back into Reporting services configuration manager and confrim which instance it's pointing to, this should be the instance that the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases reside on.